# App Crashing trying to reach storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm getting an error connecting to my storyboard. I have a navigation controller connected to my view controller as a root. Everytime I play the application, it crashes. I get this error:

> Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   (lldb)
>
> scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier-

What's this even mean?

My view controller is defined right under the normal code.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//some code here
```

Comment: Do you have a class named AboutMeViewController? Check spelling and capitalization carefully.

Comment: Yep. I do. Everything is the EXACT same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I transferred the storyboard from another project, it was linked to another project. I refreshed the "Custom Class"/"File Owner". Usually it's hidden and it confuses people but it's there. To locate it find the newspaper looking like icon and press on it. It'll be the first option all the way at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the scenes in your Storyboard is (a) referencing a class, AboutMeViewController, which you haven't defined.

It further sounds like this scene also doesn't have any segues pointing to it, nor does it have a unique identifier. Thus there's no way to load it.

Select each scene in your storyboard in turn, select the outermost view controller object, and use the identity inspector to see the class of that view controller.

Comment: AboutMeViewController is a View Controller. I have refrenced is as class AboutMeViewController: UIViewController {

Comment: Ok, I figured it was a view controller. Where is the class AboutMeViewController defined? Edit your post to show the definition of that class.